# OpenGL ES 2.0: Controlling Transparency in Fragment Shader

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl

The following is the OpenGL ES 2.0 simple **GLSL Fragment Shader**, I use to place textures on polygons, to render 2D sprites.

```
varying mediump vec2 TextureCoordOut;
uniform sampler2D Sampler;

void main()
{
gl_FragColor = texture2D(Sampler, TextureCoordOut);
//gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(Sampler, TextureCoordOut).xyz, TextureCoordOut.w * 0.5);

}
```

The fragment shader places voxels with alpha information taken from the source 2D texutre(.png image). Apart from alpha information, I need to control overall polygon/sprite transparency to achieve **Fade In/Fade Out** effects.

Could you show me, please, how to **modify the above shader** to control the overall transparency, besides the alpha information?

*Note: The commented out line is used for my attempts to achieve the transparency. I wish to **combine** both the alpha information with the overall polygon/sprite transparency.*

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably cleaner solution, which also doesn't require to ask texture unit two times.

```
void main()
{
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(Sampler, TextureCoordOut);
  gl_FragColor.a *= 0.5;
}
```

(maybe compiler does that for you, but what if not. Especially on the opengl-es device performance difference *may be observed*)

Comment: +1, Agreed, and I will modify my code according to your idea. Let me mar yor answer as the _Accepted Answer_ as well.

Comment: I was under the impression that you cannot set gl_FragColor multiple times. Once you set it, the color is fed into the frame buffer. Is that a limitation on newer version of OpenGL? Maybe ES?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, I found the soultion.

*This is the correct line in Fragment Shader:*

```
    gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(Sampler, TextureCoordOut).xyz, texture2D(Sampler, TextureCoordOut).w * 0.5);
```

Thanks anyway.